# Continue function to the limit of axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the `stat_function` to plot some functions. I want to add a limit on the y-axis but then the curve will stop before the actual limit. I suspect that ggplot will calculate some points on the curve and interpolate the rest but if the next point is higher than the limit it will be left out. Is it possible to force ggplot to actually plot the curve up to the limit?
The Problem with such a curve is, that it looks like the curve intentionally ended there.

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

radius <- function(h, s){
  return((4 * h^2 + s^2) / 8 * h )
}

p <-ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0.0, 20)), aes(x))

plot(
p + stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="10"), args=list(s=10))
  + stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="20"), args=list(s=20))
  + stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="30"), args=list(s=30))
  + stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="40"), args=list(s=40))
  + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1000))
)
```

[image: the cut of curve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you encounter is that `stat_y_continuous()` simply ignores values that  lie outside of the range specified. Since the last point that lies below `y = 1000` does not have the same value for `y` for each of the curves, they do not end at the same `y` value.

There are several ways to solve this, depending on what you actually want. One possibility is to use `coord_cartesian()` instead of `scale_y_continuous()`. This keeps all the values, and simply cuts off the coordinate axes:

```
p + stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="10"), args=list(s=10)) +
    stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="20"), args=list(s=20)) +
    stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="30"), args=list(s=30)) +
    stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="40"), args=list(s=40)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1000))
```

[image]

As you can see, this draws to curves until they reach the upper range of the plot area.

If you really want the curves to end at `y = 1000`, you could draw more points in your `stat_function`. This still means that the curves do not end at exactly `y = 1000`, but they will end so close to that limit that the difference is no longer visible:

```
p + stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="10"), args=list(s=10), n = 2000) +
  stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="20"), args=list(s=20), n = 2000) +
  stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="30"), args=list(s=30), n = 2000) +
  stat_function(fun=radius, aes(color="40"), args=list(s=40), n = 2000) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1000))
```

[image]